# Launcher restart by system

Tags: android, restart, activity-manager

on android platform, I kill an application(for example Launcher) at shell by command: kill -9 pid,  the proccess is killed.  then after a second , the apk  be restarted.

Anyone know which module restart the apk? 
where is the code?

Note: I debug ActivityManagerService. Seemed someone startActivity to restart Launcher.
But I do not know who call startActivity command.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you want to kill the Launcher? Without it, your phone can't function.

Comment: I just chheck if launcher will restart if some bad thing occurs, such as coredump.  now in most cases the laucher will restart after be killed. but sometimes it can't restart. So I want to know why? who control this?

Comment: I'd say Android itself. Without the launcher you're unable to start anything on your phone, so the OS tries to keep it alive. But I wonder why you would need this information, as I can't imagine an application for this knowledge.

Comment: I'm developing platform launcher, not just an application. I hope every time laucher will be restarted if it is killed. but sometimes it is failed.